# Split a result from File.ReadAllBytes

Tags: c#, arrays

My code here reads all the bytes of a image and stores it in the byte array. Is there a way to convert these bytes into ascii then split them up to 512-char(ascii char) long pieces? Like when you try splitting a string based on the length, you can do that. Can you do something similar to splitting this into 512 lengths? This is to send to the server.

```
byte[] imagesize; 
imagesize = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\image.jpeg");
Console.Write(imagesize[1].ToString());
```

What I *really* want is to convert these bytes into plain ASCII format (Which in C# would be Encoding.ASCII), then split that long ASCII line from converting all the bytes into 512-char(?) long chunks into a byte array (byte[] chunks). So when I send the packets I can do

```
 for(i=0; i<AmountOfChunks; i++)
 {
      Packet.payload = chunks[i];
      //The "chunks" is the ASCII formated array.
 }
```

If someone knows how to do this, it would greatly help. Thanks, if there's anything more, i'll try to explain it in more detail if i can.
If this is wrong, because i know a byte is 8-bit each. Then somehow to be able to do it, maybe the bytes into a list?

Comment: Why don't you just read it in chunks then?

Comment: Those comments don't really explain anything I'm afraid, could you update your question with detailed information on what exactly you need to send to the server?

Comment: @Nom what do you expect from ASCII represantation of this int `1234567890`, `0gKWSQ==`, `D2-02-96-49` or `D2029649`? They are all correct.

Comment: Convert to ASCII *how*? base64? base85? 7-bit encoding? hexadecimal?

Comment: @L.B To be honest, I don't know exactly how this server makes the ASCII characters. This link (screen shot) is an example of the 512-char http://prntscr.com/97iec. I'm assuming it looks like ASCII, though if i'm wrong. My great apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @Nom: that's just looking at a `byte[]` as a `char[]`. Encoding simply takes character data and places it in the appropriate byte representation. If you cast byte data to some character type and look at it...well you'll get funny looking character data. Those question marks are not the values you think they are :)

Comment: Yea that's probably just raw bytes.

Comment: @harold Yeah, it's raw bytes. There we go, thats what I was trying to say. But how can i get raw bytes from an image and stuff? To send it the way I would like to.

Comment: You get the raw bytes already. There's only that odd 512-byte chunking business. Are you sending them with an UDP socket?

Comment: @Nom sorry for the delay, I had to sleep :) Anyway if it's TCP, there should be no chunking involved. TCP will chunk itself. Just send all of it at once.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear *why* you needs this, but you might be looking for [`Convert.ToBase64String()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) to get a string representation. For chunking you can just walk over the resulting string and split at the appropriate indexes:

```
byte[] imagesize = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\image.jpeg");
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imagesize);

List<string> chunks = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < base64String.Length; i+=512)
{
    chunks.Add(base64String.Substring(i, Math.Min(512, base64String.Length - i)));
}
```

Comment: I need this to send a packet to a server, which the max length is 512 characters, so to send a whole image to the server, it needs to be split up into 512 chunks then sent one after another. So I needed to find a way to split the readallbytes. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, thats why I also need to convert it to ASCII, which I can attempt to do, but if you know the proper code to do it, it can be a great help.

Comment: @Nom There are many ways to convert the binary data to ASCII strings. What format does your server expects?

Comment: @L.B I believe it's just the standard ASCII string. It just doesn't accept raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this

```
int i=0;  
do
{
     sendBytes = imagesize.Skip(512*i).Take(512).ToArray();
     //Your function of send
     i++;
}
while(imagesize.Count()-512*i>0)
```